# HttpStatusCode is any 500 type

Tags: c#, http-status-codes

I was wondering if there was an easier way (nicer way) to check for a 500 status code?

The only way I can think of doing this is by doing:

```
var statusCodes = new List<HttpStatusCode>()
{
  HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,
  HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout,
  HttpStatusCode.HttpVersionNotSupported,
  HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
  HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented,
  HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable
};
if (statusCodes.Contains(response.StatusCode))
{
  throw new HttpRequestException("Blah");
}
```

I noticed these are the 500 types:

- BadGateway
- GatewayTimeout
- HttpVersionNotSupported
- InternalServerError
- NotImplemented
- ServiceUnavailable

Comment: you could check the numeric range 500..599

Comment: Bah didn't realise they were castable :$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Status codes starting with 5xx is a server error, so the simple method would be

```
if ((int)response.StatusCode>=500 && (int)response.StatusCode<600)
      throw new HttpRequestException("Server error");
```

Comment: bonus: `bool success = ((int)response.StatusCode) >= 200 && ((int)response.StatusCode) < 300;`

Comment: To avoid use of a magic number: `(int)response.StatusCode >= (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError`

Comment: Why not just `response.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError`?